# D3 v4 date label return the wrong format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm using react v16 and D3 to draw a simple graph, but the x-axis returns the wrong format, as you can see below;

[image]

The format supposed to be %Y-%m-%d,  it even mixes hour.

Below is how I convert the data, quite simple there nothing complicated;

```
const parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
let max = 0, min = 0;

let timeData = recommended_time_historical.map((v,i) => {

  max = Math.max(v.score, max);
  min = Math.min(v.score, min);

  return {
    date: parseDate(v.label),
    score: v.score
  };

})
```

And the D3 code is below;

```
// omitted for brevity 

// set the ranges
const x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, (d)=> {
  return d.date;
}));
y.domain([min,max]);

let area = d3.area()...
// omitted for brevity

// add the X gridlines
chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d"))
  )

// add the Y gridlines
chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat("")
  )


// add the area
chart.selectAll()
  .data([data]).enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area)    

// omitted for brevity

chart.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

chart.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Comment: it should be `d3.timeFormat` in the `.tickFormat`

Comment: thank you all......

Answer (score -1):

You can not parse time again in d3 axisBottom, but have to define time format by which you can see the ticks label in axis. So replace timeParse with timeFormat in d3 axisBottom.

```
// X GridLines
chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(
        d3.axisBottom(x)
            .tickFormat(function (data) {
                return d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")(data);
            });
    );
```

Comment: Please add some sentences to your answer so that people also understand your answer